# EF Core 3.1: Update a single record

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext, savechanges, ef-core-3.1

What would be the best solution for building a number sequence generator. I've to apply several different text formats to a sequence of numbers. I would like to save the current number values in a own table. When I need to draw a new number, I would like to increase the number in my table and save the new number to my table. But I have to make it independent from other (bigger) transactions, which may be running at the same time.

For better understanding my issue: I've to import a batch of sales orders. During the import I've to generate a new number sequence value, but it will happen quite in the middle of a transaction. After processing some header information I can now generate my number from the sequence. At this point I've to save this in the database, so that the next user has to draw a new number. After the number generation I've to process the order lines. Only if this is finished successful, then I'm allow to save the whole sales order in database. If errors occur, the whole sales order will be retried to be imported manually later. The used number of the sequence must not be used again.

So I need a possibility to save single records from the ChangeTracker instead of writing all modifications at once. Any idea how to deal with it?

Comment: No there isn't. Use a sequence.

Comment: I'm afraid that using a sql sequence will not my solve problem. Of course the number auto increment would work best, but we have cases, where it must be possible to manually overwrite the numbers.Also the generation of the whole text id has to run on client side. Sometimes the generation of the numbers can be more complex.